# Google apps standalone script - file picker authentication fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-picker

I'm  trying to follow the instructions for using the file picker api in a stand alone script.
For now I just want to get the "Hello World" example to work

There are a couple of different sources of this in google documentation. I ended up using this one:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker

What I did was copy and paste html code to an html file on the script project and making the code.gs to look like this (as was described in HTML Service section of the Script Apps Guide):

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

Then I created the credentials in the console through Resources>Cloud Platform Project. I copied the developerKey, clientId and appId from the console into my code. Then I did the Version Manage and the Publish>Deploy as Webapp bits. 
When I tried the URL I got that error:
 redirect_uri_mismatch

After that I started searching and found this thread:

[Google Apps Script - Using Google's file picker on a standalone script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188017/google-apps-script-using-googles-file-picker-on-a-standalone-script)
As it was suggested there I added the

```
.setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
```

line to the pickerBuilder definition. I have updated the version, published again but I still get the same error.

So now the html code looks as follows (I changed the personal stuff):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // The Browser API key obtained from the Google API Console.
    // Replace with your own Browser API key, or your own key.
    var developerKey = 'AIzaSyDZzfmUYVhy112mmvMdGjyxu87NzKPRw2g';

    // The Client ID obtained from the Google API Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
    var clientId = "920142203274-3v3laj3p4hlvufugi6lq1r6oehal8umj.apps.googleusercontent.com"

    // Replace with your own project number from console.developers.google.com.
    // See "Project number" under "IAM & Admin" > "Settings"
    var appId = "920142203274";

    // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
    var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

    var pickerApiLoaded = false;
    var oauthToken;

    // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
    function loadPicker() {
      gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
    }

    function onAuthApiLoad() {
      window.gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
          },
          handleAuthResult);
    }

    function onPickerApiLoad() {
      pickerApiLoaded = true;
      createPicker();
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
      }
    }

    // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
    function createPicker() {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .addView(view)
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            .build();
         picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }

    // A simple callback implementation.
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
        alert('The user selected: ' + fileId);
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error is the same and looks like this:

400. That’s an error.
     Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
     The JavaScript origin in the request, https://n-lrmsso6qous3xxeujgyomegl6ggr3xob2stmi6a-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com, 
     does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. 
     Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/920149903274-3v3laj3p4hlvufugi6lq1r6oehal8umj.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=920149903274
     to update the authorized JavaScript origins.

Since I wasn't able to find the guide for my specific use case I'm using the process depiction from 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs
and the code from 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker
so I'm not entirely sure if it is really supposed to work that way. I'd be very happy to be directed to the right guide (if it exists) and to work it through.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `setOrigin` should change the origin to docs.google.com. Your error doesn't reflect the  change. 1. Can you provide the latest error? 2. Have you visited the console, as the error  recommends to change the redirect_uris. 3. Have you redployed your script after adding setOrigin?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 1. I have. This is the error I get now. 2 I have visited the  console. I'm not entirely sure how it must look. There is en entry in the Authorised redirect URIs there, it is https://script.google.com/oauthcallback. How should I change it? 3. I did redeploy, I added a version and did the publish->deploy again

Comment: I used this guide in the first place. The thing is - I cannot use the code that is posted there since it is intended to be used in the sheets app while I want it to work on a standalone app (actually I checked and inside the gsheet it works ok). So I used this guide for the step-by-step process but used the code example from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker. I couldn't find a guide for the case I need.

Comment: I believe the issue is Two different cloud projects- the picker one vs the standalone script. Try changing the script's project to the picker's one.Resources>Cloud Platform Project. (Also,`since it is intended to be used in the sheets app while I want it to work on a standalone app` isn't a big deal. It's easy to adapt)