# How to change bound script to unbound for selecting, editing, and creating derivative google docs in drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, unbound

I developed a bound script with a UI accessible from a menu extension and clickable dropdown items embedded in a google doc file.  The purpose of the script is to transition from the starting document template, allow team collaboration and editing, and after team approval, transition the final edit of the google doc into a pdf file for storage in the team archive.

As a bound script, this implementation works partially and clumsily because the script extension does not always persist through derivative documents, and cannot programatically close the parent doc editor and open another editor instance for the child document.  I am hoping that changing the script platform from bound to unbound might enable a higher level of process control.  What I have in mind is the following:

1. a persistent popup dialog which, given a folder name or ID, would invoke a google drive file selector,
2. after selection of a google doc file, enable simple document editing operations already implemented in the bound script,
3. after custom editing of the new document, upon a button click perform the file copying/moving operations already implemented in the bound script, and
4. close the edit window of the parent document and open a new edit window for the child document.

Any unbound script examples or guidance in how to implement the file selector and edit open/close functions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout [tag:google-picker] and `window.open()`

Comment: You may want to review [Google Apps Script - Using Google's file picker on a standalone script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44199315), [Apps Script - Custom Sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) _(where you could load an html file where the Google picker process starts)_ & also this resource [Using Google Picker with Google Apps Script](https://www.labnol.org/code/20039-google-picker-with-apps-script)